# How large can be the dimension of a complex matrix which Mathematica can handle to find its eigenalues?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I have been working with 12 cross 12 complex matrix in Mathematica ,   I need to work with bigger size matrix of the dimension of the order of hundreds ,  I was wondering if Mathematica can handle this much.I am using Mathematica 9 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I am sure M can handle 64 by 64 size matrix.

Comment: What's keeping you from trying?

Comment: If the matrix is comprised of approximate numbers then yes, there will be no trouble going much larger. If they are exact numbers you can still go somewhat larger. If symbolic, it may depend on sparsity patterns, but chances are intermediate computations will get bloated fairly quickly. Absent information on these specifics, it is not possible to say anything much more concrete.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if you provide relevant background on type calculations you want to do, the maximum dimensions of the matrix, whether it is sparse or not and whether it requires symbolic evaluations.

In principle Mathematica is efficient enough for handling most Matrix manipulations.

The memory constraint will largely be outside of Mathematica as typically the amount of memory available is constrained by the physical number of bytes of RAM in the computer including "virtual memory" obtained by swapping data to your hard drive (less what's been used by other programs).

This swapping is however slowing down your calculations tremendously.

You can eat up a lot of memory if you start doing manipulations on symbolic matrices.

Suggest you check with `MemoryInUse[]` for insight in how much memory your sessions are using and `ByteCount[yourMatrix]` on how big your matrix is. Also, read up on `SparseArray[]`, that will possibly give you substantial additional mileage.